# How do I unscramble a scrambled word?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, scramble

Supposed I have an array of char {A,B,C,D,E,F} and the order number is 3

Then, the scrambled word is as follow :

The first 3rd (order number) character, C is removed and saved.

{A,B,D,E,F} , {C}

Start from the following character which is D, and the first third character would be F. So, F is removed and saved.

{A,B,D,E} , {C,F}

Start from the following character (since it reached end of array index, we go back to the beginning). So start from character A, and the first third character is D.

{A,B,E} , {C,F,D}

and so on.

The resulting will be an empty original char array, and the scrambled array

{ } , {C,F,D,B,E,A}

The above algorithm can be easily implemented. I have no problems with that. What I do have problem with is unscrambling it. I am given some unscrambled char array, and its ordering, and I have to find its original char array.

I have been trying for hours now and I can't seem to find a "formula" for it. I'm guessing I'm missing something crucial. Can anyone give me a clue or hint on how to approach this problem?

Comment: You know the size, so `......` then put `C` in 3rd pos so `..C...` then you know `F` is 3 more on the right from `C` so `..C..F` then `D` is `3` on the right from `F` so you end up on the `C` (using the end of array rule you had) and because the spot is taken, use the next spot and so on

Comment: (removing the java tag, there's no java in this question)

Comment: it's an example.. taking your own example as basis, if that makes thing clear: "then put C in 3rd pos" should be  "then put the first char of the scrambled array in the `order number`-th pos"

Comment: Got it. Accidentally deleted instead of editing my comment. It makes sense now! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

1. Make "map string" the same length as your original, but with all the letters in sequence, like "ABCDEFGH.."
2. Scramble it according to the given ordering
3. Now, iterate through your problem string and the map string at the same time.  For each character in the problem string, the map string character will say where to put it.  If you have map="SQEG..." and problem="DSEG...", then 'D' goes in the 'S' position, 'S' goes in the 'Q' position, etc.

That's it.  If you prefer, or if your problem string is too long, use an array of integers instead of a string for the map.